# Using import on second java file doesn't allow access to its variables

Tags: java, file, class, import

I am trying to access a variable from a second class called Graph in Graph.java from main file called Prim.java.

I have tried Graph.variable, as well as trying to do:

```
import Graph;
```

But that receives an error saying "expected ."

Here is the Prim.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;  // Import the File class
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  // Import this class to handle errors
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prim{
    
    int min(boolean [] mst, int [] weights){
            int minweights = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int vert = -1;
            
            for (int i = 0; i <Graph.v ; i++) { // here is the issue
                if(mst[i]==false && minweights>weights[i]){
                    minweights = weights[i];
                    vert = i;
                }
            }
            
            return vert;
            
    }
```

There is more to the file, of course, so if the entire file is needed, I'd be happy to post it.

Here is the entire Graph.java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;  // Import the File class
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  // Import this class to handle errors
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Graph{
    

    public static class xGraph{
        public int v;
        public int m[][];

        public xGraph(int vert) {
            this.v = vert;
            m = new int[vert][vert];
        }

        public void edges(String start, String end, int weight) {   
            System.out.print("(" + start + ", " + end + ", " + weight + ") ");
            int numStart = convertToNum(start);
            int numEnd = convertToNum(end);
            m[numStart][numEnd]=weight;            
            m[numStart][numEnd] = weight;
            
        }
        
        
        public static int convertToNum(String s) {
            char ss = s.charAt(0);
            int num = 0;
            for (char a = 'a'; a <= 'z'; a++) {
                if (a == ss) {
                    
                    num = (a-'a');
                    
                }
            }
            
            return num;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

How is this supposed to be accomplished?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand. You are asking for `Graph.v`, but there is no such thing. The only thing `Graph` contains is `xGraph`, and even that is only a class declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to import Graph if:
 - both Classes are in default package.

 - both Classes are in same package.

 Also, you'll have to initialize static inner class like this before using it in Prime class:

```
Graph.xGraph xgrph = new Graph.xGraph(10);
for (int i = 0; i <xgrph.v ; i++) { 
     //code
}
```

Note, here xGraph is a static inner class, but it's fields `v` and `m[][]` are not static. So you need instance of the inner class to access the fields.

If you have different versions of the graphs like `xGraph`, `yGraph`, `specialGraph` ,then you can use inheritance:

```
public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Graph grph = new xGraph(10);
        for (int i = 0; i <grph.getV() ; i++) { 
           //code
        }
    }
}

interface  Graph{

    public int getV();
    public int[][] getM();
    public void edges(String start, String end, int weight);
    
    //helper methods
    public static int convertToNum(String s) {
        char ss = s.charAt(0);
        int num = 0;
        for (char a = 'a'; a <= 'z'; a++) {
            if (a == ss) {
                num = (a-'a');
            }
        }
        return num;
    }
}

class xGraph implements Graph {
    private  int v;
    private int m[][];

    public xGraph(int vert) {
        this.v = vert;
        m = new int[vert][vert];
    }

    
    @Override
    public void edges(String start, String end, int weight) {
        System.out.print("(" + start + ", " + end + ", " + weight + ") ");
        int numStart = Graph.convertToNum(start);
        int numEnd = Graph.convertToNum(end);
        m[numStart][numEnd]=weight;            
        m[numStart][numEnd] = weight;
    }


    @Override
    public int getV() {
        return this.v;
    }


    @Override
    public int[][] getM() {
        return this.m;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is good information to have. Thank you.
It still doesn't recognize Graph.v inside Prim though.

Comment: I'm running javac Prim.java Graph.java

Comment: Oh, sweet. Thank you. I'll get on that now.

Comment: Would it be better to take out the xGraph class completely and just move it's variables to Graph?

Comment: If you have only one version of the graph then move xGraph stuff to Graph. But if you are going to have different flavors of graph then it's good to use inheritance. I've updated the answer.

Comment: There is no variable ``Graph.v``. Please read about inner classes.